# With the lazy.nvim plugin manager, lazy's init() function is triggering the lazy's config() function, not sure why

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I'm going through the README file for lazy.nvim to get more familiar with it. Over the course of experimenting, I ran into something odd and I can't figure out what is going on.

I am loading the "blah" plugin "/root/projects/blah". This directory contains two submodules, "lua/bar/init.lua" and "lua/foo/init.lua".

The contents of "bar/init.lua" are `vim.cmd("set number")`
The contents of "foo/init.lua" are `vim.cmd("set background=light")`

I have this for my "nvim/init.lua" file:

```
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("lazy").setup({
        {
                -- point to a local dir
                dir = "/root/projects/blah",
                lazy = true,

                -- this will run when plugin is loaded
                config = function()
                        require('foo')
                end,

                -- this will run every time at startup
                init = function()
                        --require('bar')
                end,
        },
}, { })
```

Note that I have `require('bar')` commented out. With it commented out, the background remains dark and there are no line numbers. This is expected. However, if I uncomment out `require('bar')`, I have line numbers from "bar/init.lua" and I have a light background from "foo/init.lua".

I can't figure out why "foo.init.lua" does not run with `require('bar')` commented out and why it gets run with it commented back in.

**UPDATE: ** If I change `require('bar')` to something like `vim.g.blah = 10`, the config function does not get called and so "foo/init.lua" does not get run and the background remains black, as originally expected.